# Can we provide integers inside if condition in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

```
echo "enter a number:\c"
read num

if [ $num ] then
    echo "you are inside if"  
else
    echo "you are inside else"  
fi
```

If we enter 0 as num and 1 as num, it is showing "you are inside if"

Answer (score 1):

`if [ $num ]`

just tests whether `$num` is a non-empty string, it doesn't check the numeric value. You should use

```
if [ "$num" -ne 0 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

See [*Barmar*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62965741/6136214).  On a side note the `bash` shell also allows
us to do:

```
if (( "$num" ))
```